# Wordpress: PHP echo inside echo?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm using the below code in my header.php file to have a different div depending on the page:

```
<?php
if ( is_singular( 'movie' ) ) {
     echo "<div class='heroImagePage' style='background-image:url(blur.jpg);'>";
} elseif (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
    echo "<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); ?> <div class='heroImage' style='background-image:url(<?php echo $image[0]; ?>);'>";
} else {
    echo "<div class='heroImagePage' style='background-image:url(blur.jpg);'>";
}
?>
```

The conditions for `if ( is_singular( 'movie' ) ) {` and `else {` work fine, but the one that checks if there's a featured image doesn't. The code in there is to get the URL of the featured image so it can insert it as the div's background image. I think the issue is the echo inside an echo?

When I look at the code it outputs in my browser, it looks like this:

```
<div class="heroImage" style="background-image:url(<?php echo ; ?>);">
```

I've tried and looked online to help fix it, but can't seem to find a solution. Appreciate any help.

Comment: That's not how PHP works. Try starting here and reading a bit about PHP syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP won't execute within a string. Simply assign the `$image` variable *before* echo-ing the string

```
elseif (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(
        get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
    echo '<div class="heroImage" style="background-image:url(', $image[0], ')">';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try assigning the `$image` variable before echoing the string.
I.e.

```
<?php
if ( is_singular( 'movie' ) ) {
     echo "<div class='heroImagePage' style='background-image:url(blur.jpg);'>";
} elseif (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
    echo "<div class='heroImage' style='background-image:url" . $image[0] . ')">' ; 
} else {
    echo "<div class='heroImagePage' style='background-image:url(blur.jpg);'>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why is this answer -2 and the accepted answer is +2 but they both say exactly the same thing, almost word for word?

Comment: Don't know, when I answered there were no other answers, I had an upvote, then ended up at -3!